# Update the parent states from a distant child in React without repeating myself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Many similar questions were answered by assuming the child is one level deep. However, consider the following structure for a simple movie search app:

```
ViewPort
    Form (search bar and a submit button)
    DisplayZone (to display multiple containers)
        Container
            MovieImg
            DeleteButton
```

For now, I have made a `movies` state at the `ViewPort` level where `movies` is a list of movies called from some API.

I would like to rerender the page when `DeleteButton` is clicked. This action involves creating a `newState` that stores all movies that don't match the `id` passed by the button, and then update the `movies` state to this `newState`.

### The Problem

The `DeleteButton` is multiple levels below the `ViewPort`. My current implementation can be explained by the following pseudo-code:

```
DeleteButton Component
  removeMovie() => calls this.props.delete(id)
  render() => <button onClick={this.removeShow}/>

Container Component
  removeMovie(id) => calls this.props.delete(id)
  render() => <DeleteButton id={this.props.id} delete={this.removeShow}/>

DisplayZone Component
  removeMovie(id) => calls this.props.delete(id)
  render() => <Container id={this.props.id} delete={this.removeShow}/>

ViewPort Component
  removeMovie(id) => set a new state
  render() => <DisplayZone delete={this.removeShow}/>
```

As you can see, I had to create the same `removeMovie` method at every parent level above `DeleteButton`, and had to pass in the `id` and `delete` props to each component.

If anything, the biggest takeaway from computer science classes is to not repeat myself. But this level of repetition is clearly frustrating, and would be problematic if I want a child that is 100+ level deep from the root to update the state of the root.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can use context instead, but I'm doubtful 4 levels deep justifies it. Now, if you had to use the same state in, say, 8 separate components (regardless of nesting), I think it'd be worth considering. It can solve problems, but can also make code less maintainable. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Either use context, or use events? You're still just running on a web page, your viewport can do a `document.addEventListener(\`movies:remove\`, evt => this.removeMovies(evt))` and your button can run `document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(\`movies:remove\`), { detail: { id: ... }}))` just like anything else on a web page and dispatch/listen for events =)

Comment: Why are you rewriting it at every level and not just passing down the method from the top level through props to the level that will call the method?

Comment: @pilchard I think the `delete` prop is how I pass the method. I wrote `removeMovie` at every level because I had to pass the `id` from the button all the way to parent.  If I were to only pass the method down through props without rewriting a `removeMovie` method at every level, is there a way to pass the `id` up?